# How to make remote (ssh) user as local user?

Tags: linux, ssh, users

How one can differentiate between remote user and local user, i.e how any application will find out that logged in user is the remote one and not local user?

I want to run an application on aws, but application is exiting with an error by stating that remote users are not allowed, I have no access to application code, but I think, if I can bypass this check by making application believe that user is local and not the remote one, it should work.

so basic doubt are

1. How to differentiate between local user and remote(ssh) user ?
2. How to hack (as I am root) remote user session to make it look like local user ?

Comment: Installing and running `ltrace -S application` might give you some clues. It might be as simple as looking for SSH_CONNECTION as an environment variable.

Comment: yeah , I tried using strace , but no clue

Comment: `ltrace` is probably better than `strace` for this problem, particularly if the application is written ib C or C++.

Comment: 1) As "ssh user", `env | grep SSH_`. 2) Only ask 1 question per Question.